# Landing on a subpage on my Wix website redirects to the home page

Tags: redirect

My website on wix (https://www.villotec.com/) has a bug that I am having difficulty fixing. For some reason, when I go on a webpage that is not the home page (https://www.villotec.com/lorawan-lightning-detector for example) , it redirects to the home page as soon as the page is loading.

Why does this happen? Is there a setting on Wix that I turned on automatically?

Comment: Hey! Did you manage to solve this? I currently have the same problem

Comment: I ended up hiring someone on Fiverr to fix it for me. He never told my why it was happening because he was charging me an arm to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Figured it out though. If you're using the Wix Language Menu, go into the settings and click the Redirect Tab. It defaults to "Automatically redirect all visitors by their language". I set it to No Redirect and that fixed the issue for me. Hope that helps.[Screenshot of Language settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iqMa.png)